# SQL Query : Calculate Percentage per month per user of Total count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below query gives me the first four columns below :

```
 declare @begindate DateTime,
        @enddate DateTime 

Select @begindate =Dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-3,0)
      ,@enddate=EOMONTH(Dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-1,0))
select p.username 'Approver'
,p.Code 'Status'
, count(p.PaymentRequestId) 'Monthly Count' 
,Datename(Month,p.max_date) 'Month'

from 
       (
        select  su.UserName,pr.PaymentRequestId,prs.Code ,max(pr.CreateDateTime) 'Max_Date' 
        from PaymentRequestStatusHistory pr
        inner join hydradb..SystemUser su on pr.systemuserid = su.SystemUserId
        inner join hydradb..PaymentRequestStatus prs on prs.PaymentRequestStatusid = pr.PaymentRequestStatusid
        where 1=1 
        and (convert(date,pr.CreateDateTime)  BETWEEN @begindate
            AND DATEADD(ms, - 2, DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @enddate))))
        and pr.PaymentRequestStatusId in (3,4)
        and su.systemuserid in ( 414, 336, 12)
        group by su.UserName,pr.PaymentRequestId,prs.Code
        )p
group by p.UserName,p.Code,  Datename(Month,p.max_date)
order by p.UserName,p.code
```

Now I have to create an additional column calculating the percentage of total 'Monthly count' Per month per user per Status. For Example: In December, 
The monthly Count is 2786 (mrob Approved 2785 and rsimm approved 1), I need to calculate the percentage of the total per month. In December, mrob has Approved 99.96% and rsimm has approved 0.035%.

Like these below

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Window function to group by month the totals and then use this quantity to divide the calculated value in the row. I am not fully sure if the provided code will work as cannot tested but should be something quite similar:

```
DECLARE @begindate DateTime,
        @enddate DateTime 

SELECT @begindate = Dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-3,0)
      ,@enddate   = EOMONTH(Dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-1,0))

SELECT p.username 'Approver'
      ,p.Code 'Status'
      ,count(p.PaymentRequestId) 'Monthly Count' 
      ,Datename(Month,p.max_date) 'Month'
      ,count(p.PaymentRequestId)/Count(p.PaymentRequestID) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY Datename(Month,p.max_date)) AS 'Percentage'
FROM 
       (
        select  su.UserName,pr.PaymentRequestId,prs.Code ,max(pr.CreateDateTime) 'Max_Date' 
        FROM PaymentRequestStatusHistory pr
        INNER JOIN hydradb..SystemUser su on pr.systemuserid = su.SystemUserId
        INNER JOIN hydradb..PaymentRequestStatus prs 
        on prs.PaymentRequestStatusid = pr.PaymentRequestStatusid
        WHERE 1=1 
        AND (convert(date,pr.CreateDateTime)  BETWEEN @begindate
        AND DATEADD(ms, - 2, DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @enddate))))
        AND pr.PaymentRequestStatusId in (3,4)
        AND su.systemuserid in ( 414, 336, 12)
        GROUP BY su.UserName,pr.PaymentRequestId,prs.Code
        ) p
GROUP BY p.UserName,p.Code,  Datename(Month,p.max_date)
ORDER BY p.UserName,p.code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select . . . ,
       count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by Datename(Month, p.max_date), status) as ratio
```

Comment: this is how its giving me : 
0.011904761904
1.000000000000
0.999641062455
1.000000000000
1.000000000000
1.000000000000
0.988095238095
0.000358937544

Comment: I modified like this :
count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by Datename(Month, p.max_date), p.code) as ratio

It's giving me the values
ratio
1.190476190476

100.000000000000

99.964106245513

100.000000000000

100.000000000000
100.000000000000
98.809523809523
0.035893754486

Comment: Now I have the fix the decimal places to say 1.19%, 100.00%, 99.96% etc..

Comment: @user9273914 . . . That is a formatting issue.  Multiply by 100 and convert to a decimal(5, 2) or something similar.